# escape quote in django extra clause

Tags: sql, django, escaping

In Django, the following statement

```
entity_name = "a string with a ' quote"
Fiche.objects.extra(where=["'%s' LIKE fiche_name+'%s' " % (entity_name,'%%')])
```

causes the Database error:

```
DatabaseError: ('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

If I print the sql that is sent to db backend, I see something like this:

```
... 'a string with a ' quote' LIKE fiche_name+'%%'
```

so I tried to escape the quote in my string with a backslash

```
entity_name = "a string with a \\\' quote"
```

This time, the query seems to be well prepared for the DB backend (quote escaped):

```
... 'a string with a \' quote' LIKE fiche_name+'%%'
```

but this results in the same database error.

Does someone know how to escape properly the quote?

EDIT: I found a solution to my problem: I replace in my string each quote by two quotes and it works now:

```
entity_name = entity_name.replace("'","''")
```

Answer (score 0):

Way too late, but the right way to do this is to pass the variables as arguments to [.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
entity_name = "a string with a ' quote"
Fiche.objects.extra(where=["%s LIKE fiche_name + '%%'")], params=[entity_name])
```

Note: what you are doing is the opposite of what is normally done (`field LIKE 'pattern%'`), but it's possible nonetheless. Also note that this is database-specific code, not all databases use `+` as string concatenator (you may have to switch it to `||` or `CONCAT()`).